# git push failed unpack failed: error The lease on index has expired

Tags: git

while trying to migrate git repository to a new git repo we are getting the following error:

```
error: remote unpack failed: error The lease on index-04b199d6563a45a4ae9a17ceaf5832a8, owner 3ffdcc58-cf29-4458-97ae-619dffd7251c, obtained on 12/23/2020 6:03:10 PM by process 96d60301-0e15-41e8-99b4-897b3f48f837 has expired on 12/23/2020 6:08:55 PM
To https://dev.azure.com/mycollection/_git/test
! [remote rejected] master -> master (The lease on index-04b199d6563a45a4ae9a17ceaf5832a8, owner 3ffdcc58-cf29-4458-97ae-619dffd7251c, obtained on 12/23/2020 6:03:10 PM by process 96d60301-0e15-41e8-99b4-897b3f48f837 has expired on 12/23/2020 6:08:55 PM)
error: failed to push some refs to https://dev.azure.com/mycollection/_git/test
```

we tried to run `git fsck`, clone the repo again on new folder, `git gc` and nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the host at `dev.azure.com`.  If you're running that host, you can fix it.  If not, there's not a lot you can do about it.

(The expired lease indicates that they are using a distributed file system and have not given themselves enough time to get their own work done.  How hard or easy this is to fix is not something I can guess, as I don't have enough information.  If it's load-dependent—and it probably is—you might have better luck at some other time of day, for instance, if their load is time-varying.  But really, this is Microsoft's fault.  You've fallen afoul of Leslie Lamport's description of a distributed system:

> A distributed system is one in which the failure of a computer you didn't even know existed can render your own computer unusable.

See https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Leslie_Lamport.)